# Let $f : X → Y$ be a continuous closed surjection such that $f^{–1}(y)$ is compact for all $y ∈ Y .$

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : X → Y$ be a continuous closed surjection such that $f^{–1}(y)$ is compact for all $y ∈ Y .$ Suppose that $X$ is Hausdorff. Prove that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

I have that $f$ is a qoutient map, but I can not think of anythink useful to do with that.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By taking complements, you can give the following equivalent definition for the Hausdorff condition:

> A topological space $X$ is Hausdorff if given $x,y\in X$ there exist two closed sets $U,V\subset X$ such that $x\notin U$, $y\notin V$ and $U\cup V=X$.

Now back to your problem. Let $y_1,y_2\in Y$, we will construct two closed sets $U_1,U_2$ in $Y$ satisfying the conditions above. Since $f^{-1}(y_1)$ and $f^{-1}(y_2)$ are compact, we can use the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff to separate them using two open sets. Taking their complements, we get two closed sets $V_1,V_2\subset X$ with $f^{-1}(y_i)\cap V_i=\emptyset$ and $V_1\cup V_2 = X$. Then $U_1=f(V_1)$, $U_2=f(V_2)$ are the closed sets in $Y$ we were looking for.

I leave it to you to prove the details.

Answer (score 0):

Just take $y, y' ∈ Y$. Their preimages are compact disjoint subsets of $X$ and so can be separated by disjoint open sets. Complements of images of these sets are open disjoint and separating $y, y'$ in $Y$.