# Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact. If $X$ is Hausdorff, then $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology

I was trying to prove that when $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous, surjective, closed map, such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact for all $y\in Y$, and $X$ is Hausdorff, then $Y$ is also Hausdorff. I found some help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605784/let-f-x-%E2%86%92-y-be-a-continuous-closed-surjection-such-that-f-1y-is-compa). However, I've worked out what was suggested, but I feel I don't need the fact that $f$ is continuous and surjective. Can someone tell me where I need this?

Can someone tell me where I need this?

Comment: Continuity is definitely not needed

Comment: Surjectivity is needed to ensure the preimages of $y_1$ and $y_2$ are nonempty.

Comment: The preimage  of y being compact has to be for all preimages.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Thanks! However, in the question is stated that $f$ is continuous, so I'm still a bit confused..

Comment: @user665297 Having an extra hypothesis is not a bad thing. Also because there is a special term for "closed, continuous, surjective function such that the preimage of every point is compact" -- a perfect map.

Comment: The assumption about $f$ being surjective is crucial. The counterexample is a constant function.

Comment: Thanks all, it's clear now!

Answer (score 1):

> If $f:X \to Y$ is closed, has compact fibres ($\forall y \in Y: f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is compact) and is surjective (onto) then $X$ Hausdorff implies $Y$ Hausdorff.

Continuity of $f$ is not needed for that result. (but the combination of closed onto continuous and compact fibres is so common that it has a special name: $f$ is perfect).

The proof follows from the facts that

1. In a Hausdorff space $X$ disjoint compact sets have disjoint open neighbourhoods.
2. If $f: X \to Y$ is closed and $f^{-1}[\{y\}] \subseteq O$ for some $y \in Y$ and $O$ open in $X$, then there is an open neighbourhood $O'$ of $y$ such that $f^{-1}[O'] \subseteq O$. (in fact, $O'=Y\setminus f[X\setminus O]$ will do.)